# Monadic operations within data type?

Tags: haskell, operators, monads

I've come across the use of `:>>=` in the [Haxl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxl) library that I am using. I'm unsure how this is different from the `>>=` operator?

For example:

```
data MyType a = MyType a :>>= (a -> Int)
```

What exactly is this operation doing in `MyType`?

This is the context of it's using in Haxl:

```
newtype GenHaxl u a = GenHaxl { unHaxl :: Env u -> IORef (RequestStore u) -> IO (Result u a) } --|| u is the env, a is the result

data Result u a
  = Done a
    | Throw SomeException
    | Blocked (Cont u a)

data Cont u a
  = Cont (GenHaxl u a)
    | forall b. Cont u b :>>= (b -> GenHaxl u a)
    | forall b. (Cont u (b -> a)) :<*> (Cont u b)
    | forall b. (b -> a) :<$> (Cont u b)
```

Comment: @jd823592 Haxl library is already mentioned in question

Comment: Sorry I am an idiot, I misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a constructor for the type `Cont u a` in form of an operator. It is defined in the piece of code you included in the question.

```
Cont u a
```

is either

```
Cont (GenHaxl u a)
```

or

```
forall b. (:>>=) (Cont u b) (b -> GenHaxl u a)
```

or

```
forall b. (:<*>) (Cont u (b -> a)) (Cont u b)
```

or

```
forall b. (:<$>) (b -> a) (Cont u b)
```

the last three cases being recursive as they mention `Cont u ...`. Further in the code there is `toHaxl` which folds `Cont` and its symbolic structure into actual values by interpreting `:>>=`, `:<*>`, and `:<$>` with application of the associated `>>=` (or `>=>`) etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm used to seeing operators defined in classes, not type constructors. :-)

Comment: Of course, I find it confusing too :), but once you familiarize yourself with this way of using operators you will probably find it useful at some occasions.